# Java android client socket not getting response until after socket disconnect

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

My android app does not receive data until the socket closes (usually i force close the server, then the responses come in on the client).

Some code for any who care to see:

-Server

```
private void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);

        form.logMessage("Recieved: " + text);
        //Check commands
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            sendText(form.onCommand(text), socket);
        }
        socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);

    }

    public void sendText(string message,Socket socket)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        form.logMessage("Sending: " + message);
        socket.NoDelay = true;
        socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), socket);
        form.logMessage("Sent!");
        socket.NoDelay = false;

    }
```

-Client

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clicked send button!");
            String babam =  ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.requestText)).getText().toString();
            Log.i(TAG,"Going to send: " + babam);

                new Thread(new ResponseThread(babam)).start();


        }
    });
public class ResponseThread implements Runnable{

    String toSend;

    public ResponseThread(String toSend)
    {
        this.toSend = toSend;

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            stream.println(toSend);
            Log.i(TAG, "Sent request!");
            Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for reponse...");



            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String response = in.readLine();

            Log.i(TAG,"Response: " + response);
            statusText.setText(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's some output that I have:

-Server

```
[8/9/2015 9:04:28 PM] Recieved: roll
[8/9/2015 9:04:28 PM] Rolled dice! 6 + 4 = 10
[8/9/2015 9:04:28 PM] Sending: Rolled!
[8/9/2015 9:04:28 PM] Sent!
[8/9/2015 9:04:28 PM] Recieved: 

[8/9/2015 9:04:29 PM] Recieved: roll
[8/9/2015 9:04:29 PM] Rolled dice! 5 + 1 = 6
[8/9/2015 9:04:29 PM] Sending: Rolled!
[8/9/2015 9:04:29 PM] Sent!
[8/9/2015 9:04:29 PM] Recieved:
```

-Client

```
08-09 20:48:29.133  12801-12801/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Clicked send  button!
08-09 20:48:29.133  12801-12801/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Going to send: roll
08-09 20:48:29.158  12801-13029/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Sent request!
08-09 20:48:29.158  12801-13029/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Waiting for reponse...
08-09 20:49:04.371  12801-12801/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Clicked send button!
08-09 20:49:04.371  12801-12801/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Going to send: roll
08-09 20:49:04.382  12801-13280/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Sent request!
08-09 20:49:04.382  12801-13280/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Waiting for reponse...
08-09 20:49:37.399  12801-13029/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Response: Rolled!YepRolled!Yep
08-09 20:49:37.400  12801-13280/com.artish1.sockettest I/Client﹕ Response: null
```

Note how all the responses come all at once, and that's when i force close the server.

I'm not that experienced with sockets but I have been looking at other posts about this, some say to force flush the request. That way I can get it on the client, but I've already sent it through the server (getting confirmation through the output).

Would anyone like to take a gander?

Comment: Have you tried to flush the socket after you send the message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding a `\n` to the end of the message.  Also do not set 'NoDelay` to false.  You are doing an asynchronous send.

Comment: Alright, removed the 'NoDelay to false'. Which message should I add an \n to? There are a ton here and I'm getting sleepy, fearful of making some silly mistake

Comment: The Android  client is doing a `Readline`; so all messages to it must end in a newline.  If it doesn't the client will just spin it's wheels until the socket is closed.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't seem to work. I added an /n at the end as you asked, but I'm receiving the same results.   `message += "\\n";
            form.logMessage("Sending: " + message);`   , and still not receiving it on time. `Response: Rolled!Rolled!`

Comment: Try `message += "\n";`  Single backslash for a newline character.

Comment: Oh i forgot to tell you I've already tried the single backslash and double backslash.

Comment: So neither a single backslash or double backslash will work. I'm thinking about just closing the socket connection right there and opening it back up whenever needed.

Comment: "\n" should work. Please show your adapted code. Edit your original post please.

Comment: Ahh thanks @RichardSchneider ! That was a really strange thought on my decision to forget about the order, but I was sleepy and I woke up to this and it made me slap my forehead. Yes it worked to add that `\n` to the message and then get the bytes from it. It worked. Thank you very much :)

Comment: All socket I/O is asynchronous, and adding `\n` or setting/not setting `NoDelay` doesn't change that. Adding the line terminator does resolve the `ReadLine()` issue, but that's not what it says in your misleading answer.